# Quantile results for the entire dataframe

Tags: r, quantile

I have a fairly large data set consisting of around 100 variables and around
1 million observations. The data set contains both numeric and categorical variables.
I want to calculate the quantile for all the numeric variables, so when I try the following:
`quantile(dat1, c(.10, .30, .5, .75, .9, na.rm = TRUE)`

I get an error in R saying "non-numeric argument to binary operator"

So could anyone please suggest me the appropriate codes for this? Appreciate all your help and thanks

Comment: What is your "dat1"? Provide some data.

Comment: dat1 is the name of my dataset

Comment: If I go on computing quantile for each numerical variable in my dat1 dataset, then it would be timeconsuming, so I want to compute the quantile for all the numeric variables in a single go.

Comment: @Sathish I tried your code but it gives me combined values of all numeric columns. I want quantile results for all rows belonging to each numeric column separately. For example, if a and b are my numeric columns, then i want quantile results for a and b separately. Thanks

Comment: @Rookie The brackets in your code are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quantile of all numeric columns**

```
# sample data with numeric and character class values 
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b= 1:5, c = letters[1:5])
col_numeric <- which( sapply(df, is.numeric ) )   # get numeric column indices
quantile( x = unlist( df[,  col_numeric] ), 
          c(.10, .30, .5, .75, .9),
          na.rm = TRUE )

# 10% 30% 50% 75% 90% 
#  1   2   3   4   5
```

**Quantile of individual numeric column**

```
sapply( col_numeric, function( y ) {
  quantile( x = unlist( df[,  y ] ), 
            c(.10, .30, .5, .75, .9),
            na.rm = TRUE )
})

#       a   b
# 10% 1.4 1.4
# 30% 2.2 2.2
# 50% 3.0 3.0
# 75% 4.0 4.0
# 90% 4.6 4.6
```

Since your real data is big, you could use `data.table` library for efficiency.

```
library('data.table')
setDT(df)[, lapply( .SD, quantile, probs = c(.10, .30, .5, .75, .9), na.rm = TRUE ), .SDcols = col_numeric ]
```

Comment: Thanks Sathish, the second piece of code works perfectly for me.

Comment: Is there a way that i can store the results for the second piece of code in form of a data frame where 10%, 30%, 50%, 75% and 90% are placed in columns and the numeric variables a and b are placed as rows. Thanks again.

Comment: transpose your results by doing `data.frame( t( results ) )`